# Apache 2.4 config alias with .htaccess does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

I use the [php lumen framework](https://lumen.laravel.com/) and I'd like to design my api like this:

http://somesite.com/api/admin/staffs

Here is my apache vhost and htaccess config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:\webroot"
ServerName dsp-api.dev

Alias /api "D:\webroot\dsp-api\public"
<Directory D:\webroot\dsp-api\public>
    Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I'm sure my `mod_rewrite` is open. It seems like .htaccess file does not work any more .
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If I remove 'alias' my config is ok..I have to do this because my angularjsis in it .so dont let me use lumen route to rewrite .that would conflict with angularjs

Answer (score 0):

> Use Route Groups - https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups

## Remove `Alias /api ...` from vhost && Apache restart

## Restore public/.htaccess

## app/Http/routes.php

```
<?php

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app->version();
});

$app->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() use($app) {
    $app->get('admin/staffs', function () {
        return '/api/admin/staffs';
    });
    $app->get('admin/users', function () {
        return '/api/admin/users';
    });
});
```

## Visit

- somesite.com
- somesite.com/api/admin/staffs
- somesite.com/api/admin/users